# Unable to see boot output on MSI SLI Plus motherboard with 'Above 4G decoding' turned on

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu Server installed on my mining rig. The motherboard is an MSI Z270 SLI Plus.
If I want to use more that 3 (or maybe 4) GPUs on this motherboard then I have to select a Bios mining option that allows more cards:

```
Above 4G Decoding
Enables or disables 64-bit capable devices to be decoded in above 4G address space. It is only available if the system supports 64-bit PCI decoding.
```

Before I select this option I can see all the boot messages as Ubuntu boots. When this option is selected I see the grub menu but after that just a blank screen until the login dialogue appears.

This is pretty annoying as if there's a problem with a GPU that I have installed I just don't ever see anything. The boot hangs and I am left with a black screen (and no ssh access) forever.

I have tried `nomodeset` in the grub menu but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I also tried `no splash` and `quiet splash` I think.

I have similar issues when trying to install Ubuntu. I just get a black screen after selecting "Install Ubuntu Server" if I have this above 4G decoding turned on.

Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: I've noticed the same issue: When `Above 4G decoding` is `Enabled` in BIOS, there is a blank screen starting from `grub` up until the GDM / Xorg startup grabs the display.  Another symptom: one SATA disk (out of my 6 disks) does not show up to the kernel!  Turning off `Above 4G decoding` fixes the issue.  I still have no idea how to remedy these problems when enabling it.  Presumably it's because addressing hardware above 4GiB 64-bit address barrier is not possible during GRUB, or handoff to kernel?  Just a hypothesis, but maybe GRUB is 32-bit still?